# jQuery ui selectable not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

```
<ol>
    <li>tafe</li>
    <li>college</li>
    <li>uni</li>
    <li>school</li>
</ol>

<script>
    $("ol").selectable();
</script>
```

I am able to make a box around the elements but I am not able to select the elements either individually or in a group.

Comment: can you post  your full html?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, after I included the related libraries in the html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6cht0v0L/

The jquery code:

```
 $(function() {
      $( "#selectable-1" ).selectable();
 });
```

Here is the html:

```
 <ol id="selectable-1">
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Product 1</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Product 2</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Product 3</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Product 4</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Product 5</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Product 6</li>
     <li class="ui-widget-content">Product 7</li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: I have included these libraries in HTML still it is not working                                                      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: can you share your whole html @DSG

Comment: @DSG may I ask you to try exactly the same ones as in the code above?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with css. I had the same problem. I just included `ui-selected{background:gold;}` and it worked. Don't forget to include these all:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If your code is still not working see the exact problem using inspect element

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the call in the jQuery onload function

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "ol" ).selectable();
});
</script>
```

Doc: https://jqueryui.com/selectable/

Comment: I did try to wrap the call, but it is still not working

Comment: Can you post the full html. Something may not be correct elsewhere